# How to create a generic method to convert List<Object> into ObservableList<S> and Map<T, S>?

Tags: java, generics, javafx-8

A relative Java newbie question.

I have some code that creates an observable list `ObservableList<TableModel>` and a hash map `Map<Integer, TableModel>` from a two-dimensional list `List<List<Object>>`.

I would like to convert the code into a generic method that will work with any table model.

However, I'm stuck on knowing how to replace the specific types with generic type parameters in two places in my code.  Can anyone help me please?

My current, non-generic code is as follows:

```
//A database table is loaded into resultSet
private static List<List<Object>> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();

//...

ObservableList<TableModel> olModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Map<Integer, TableModel> mapModel = new HashMap<>();

resultSet.forEach(resultRow -> {

    //Load the observable list
    TableModel row = new TableModel();
    row.addList(resultRow);
    olModel.add(row);

    //Load the hash map
    mapModel.put(row.getPK(), row);

});
```

I'm trying to "genericise" it as follows and have indicated the places where I'm stuck:

```
//Call a generic method
loadTableOLAndHM(olModel, mapModel, resultSet);

//...

private <S, T> void loadTableOLAndHM(ObservableList<S> ol, Map<T, S> hm, List<List<Object>> rs) {

    rs.forEach(resultRow -> {

        S row = new [WHAT-GOES-HERE?] (); //(1) STUCK HERE
        row.addList(resultRow);
        ol.add( (S) row);

        hm.put( (T) row.getPK(), (S) row); //(2) STUCK HERE - GETS "incompatible types" ERROR

    });

}
```

I can work around the "incompatible types" error at (2) by changing `getPK()` to return `Integer` rather than `int`, but don't know if that's the correct way of fixing it.  The DB primary key will be other data types for other tables, too, so I'm not sure what to do.

I've no idea how to fix (1).

I've read about and experimented with different ways of casting the resultSet List but none seem to work.  One other thing I've tried is passing `TableModel.class` as a parameter to the generic method but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Here is a MVCE that shows what I'm currently doing and as well as what I'd like to do. If you have time to help, I'd be most grateful.  Thank you!

I'm using JavaFX8, NetBeans 8.2 and Scene Builder 8.3.

```
package test11;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test11 extends Application {

    private static List<List<Object>> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();

    private Parent createContent() {

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane();

        //Load dummy data into resultSet for testing
        loadDummyData();

        //***********************************************************************
        //WHAT I'M CURRENTLY DOING

        //Observable list and hash map for the loaded table
        ObservableList<TableModel> olModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Map<Integer, TableModel> mapModel = new HashMap<>();

        resultSet.forEach(resultRow -> {

            //Load the observable list
            TableModel row = new TableModel();
            row.addList(resultRow);
            olModel.add(row);

            //Load the hash map
            mapModel.put(row.getPK(), row);

        });

        systemOutIt("***** CURRENT WAY ******", olModel, mapModel);

        olModel.clear();
        mapModel.clear();

        //***********************************************************************
        //WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO BE ABLE TO DO

        loadTableOLAndHM(olModel, mapModel, resultSet);

        systemOutIt("***** NEW WAY ******", olModel, mapModel);

        return content;

    }

    private <S, T> void loadTableOLAndHM(ObservableList<S> ol, Map<T, S> hm, List<List<Object>> rs) {

        rs.forEach(resultRow -> {

//==>STUCK GENERICISING THE FOLLOWING LINE:
//original line            TableModel row = new TableModel();

//            S row = new [WHAT-GOES-HERE?] ();

//            row.addList(resultRow);
//            ol.add( (S) row);

//==>STUCK GENERICISING THE FOLLOWING LINE
//Error "incompatible types:  int cannot be converted to T"
//In the Map declaration, T is Integer.
//In TableModel, getPK() returns int.

//            hm.put( (T) row.getPK(), (S) row);

        });

    }

    public static class TableModel {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty PK;
        private final SimpleStringProperty dataField;

        private TableModel() {
            this(0, "");
        }

        private TableModel(int PK, String dataField) {
            this.PK = new SimpleIntegerProperty(PK);
            this.dataField = new SimpleStringProperty(dataField);
        }

        public int getPK() {
            return PK.get();
        }

        public void setPK(int PK) {
            this.PK.set(PK);
        }

        public IntegerProperty PKProperty() {
            return PK; 
        }

        public String getDataField() {
            return dataField.get();
        }

        public void setDataField(String dataField) {
            this.dataField.set(dataField);
        }

        public StringProperty dataFieldProperty() {
            return dataField; 
        }

        public void addList(List<Object> list) {

            this.PK.set( (int) list.get(0));
            this.dataField.set( (String) list.get(1));

        }

    }

    private void loadDummyData(){

        for ( int i=1; i<4; i++ ) {
            List<Object> resultSetRow = new ArrayList<>();
            resultSetRow.add(i);
            resultSetRow.add("string"+i);
            resultSet.add(resultSetRow);
        }

    }

    private void systemOutIt(String whichWay, ObservableList<TableModel> ol, Map<Integer, TableModel> hm) {

        System.out.println(whichWay);
        System.out.println("ObservableList, size is " + ol.size());
        for ( int i=0; i<ol.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println("     ol fields = " + ol.get(i).getPK() + ", " + ol.get(i).getDataField());
            System.out.println("     map dataField value = " + hm.get(ol.get(i).getPK()).getDataField());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setHeight(250);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze the functionality you need there:

1. Create a object given a `List<Object>` (this may be split into 2 parts: creating a object and initializing the objects).
2. Get the id property from the object.

At least for the object creation you should use a object providing an implementation. If you want to combine this with initializing, you could use `Function<List<Object>, S>` for this, if you want to seperate this, use `Supplier<S>`.

For initializing and/or getting the id you could use methods of `S` itself which requires you to restrict it's type by a common base class or interfaces containing the methods for doing this. Alternatively you could use objects containing the implementations for this too, i.e. `BiConsumer<S, List<Object>>` and `Function<S, IdClass>`.

#### Example 1: Common interface implementing id/initialisation

```
public interface DatabaseObject<T> {
    void addList(List<Object> list);

    T getId();
}
```

```
private static <K, E extends DatabaseObject<? extends K>> void loadTable(ObservableList<E> ol, Map<K, E> hm, List<List<Object>> rs, Supplier<E> factory) {
    for (List<Object> resultRow : rs) {
        E o = factory.get();
        o.addList(resultRow);
        hm.put(o.getId(), o);
        ol.add(o);
    }
}
```

If you implement `DatabaseObject<Integer>` with `TableModel` you could use the method like this:

```
loadTable(olModel, mapModel, resultSet, TableModel::new);
```

#### Example 2: Using different objects containing implementations

```
private static <S, T> void loadTable(
        ObservableList<S> ol,
        Map<T, S> hm,
        List<List<Object>> rs,
        Supplier<? extends S> factory,
        BiConsumer<? super S, List<Object>> initializer,
        Function<? super S, ? extends T> idExtractor) {

    for (List<Object> resultRow : rs) {
        S o = factory.get();
        initializer.accept(o, resultRow);
        hm.put(idExtractor.apply(o), o);
        ol.add(o);
    }
}
```

```
loadTable(olModel, mapModel, resultSet, TableModel::new, TableModel::addList, TableModel::getPK);
```

---

**Note:** Be careful when storing objects based on mutable properties in a `Map`. Calling `setPK` on a object that was stored in the map could easily break your code...

Comment: Excellent, fabian, thank you very much once again.  I tried Example 2 as it's easier for me to understand.  The hash map loaded ok but the observable list was empty.  So I added `ol.add(o);` after `initializer.accept(o, resultRow);` and that worked. Thanks also for the warning about the potential for mutable properties in maps to break code.  I can see how that could happen and will remember it as I get further into writing the app.

Comment: Re Example 1.  I think I understand it now (after much reading and experimenting!) and just got it working in my app.  I changed the TableModel declaration to `public class TableModel implements DatabaseObject<Integer>` and added a `getId()` method to TableModel as follows:              `@Override
            public Integer getId() {
                return this.PK.get();
            }`.  Is that correct?  Thanks!